# Android: Undo chmod on app data directory

Tags: android, adb, chmod

Whilst trying to back up some app data into an external location I foolishly did this in `adb shell` on my Nexus 10:

```sh
run-as my.app.package
cd /data/data/my.app.package
chmod -R 666 .
```

Now of course I can't fix this as the default user:

```
shell@manta $ chmod 751 /data/data/my.app.package
Unable to chmod /data/data/my.app.package: Operation not permitted
```

but I can't `run-as` any more either:

```
shell@manta:/ $ run-as my.app.package                     
run-as: Package 'my.app.package' has corrupt installation
```

I have an unrooted tablet (which I'd prefer to keep that way) and I still want to get the data (then fix the app). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The app uid can be extracted from the /data/system/packages.xml file. Take note that this method, is subject to root access.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
#Restore app data owner and permissions
app_name=$1; data_dir=/data/data/
if [ $(pm list packages | grep $app_name) ]; then
   app_uid=$(cat /data/system/packages.xml | grep "$app_name" | \
   grep 'user' | sed -e 's/.*userId="//' -e 's/".*//')
   chown $app_uid:$app_uid $data_dir$app_name; chmod -R 751 $data_dir$app_name
else
   echo 'Doh! specified app is either not installed or mis-spelt.'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do as the default user, though, is delete all the files out of /data/data/my.app.package! That might be your best bet. Obviously you then lose all settings for that app, and you might have to reinstall it, but it should solve your problem.

You might also try clearing the data for that app in the usual way, via the Settings app.

The only alternative I can think of would be to root the tablet.

Comment: Thanks but I should probably add - the reason I was doing this was to *get* the files from that directory, so as not to lose them...

Comment: Ah, well, you can also read them as the default user, so you should be able to copy them!

Comment: It would seem only the root dir is readable now: $ ls /data/data/my.app.package/files gets me permission denied (but I can list that package's home)... presumably because the execute bit has gone :(

Comment: Ha! Forgot you'd cleared the execute bit. I think you might be screwed.